# Common Classes between portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I need to share multiple classes and properties file between portlets.

So I made a portlet Common-portlet, and in the rest of the portlets I made it as `required development context` in `liferay-plugin-package.properties.`

In eclipse, I also added the Common-portlet into the rest of the portlet's classpath.

After doing this eclipse shows no error.

But when I run the rest of the portlets it shows:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/xxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxx/util/JSONUtil.
```

Is the approach above correct?
If yes then what I am lacking. 
If no then what can be a better approach?

Comment: what do you mean by "In eclipse, I also added the Common-portlet into the rest of the portlet's classpath."?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest create one separate java project and put all the common java file inside it and 
extract the same as `.jar file` put it into `tomcat-7.0.40\lib\ext` and give a classpath refenerece from this directory or else in eclipse you can add this common project's  reference all other portlet.